# How can I have this specific class of button redirect when clicked/enter, while keeping the original functionality?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, squarespace

I have this button on a novalidate html form and I'm trying to get it to redirect to another webpage, while keeping the original functionality of creating an account.

```
<button class="yWSHVqDY3QXtLSenwRoA" data-test="create-account-create-button" type="submit"><span>Create account</span></button>
```

The end goal is for when a user creates an account, the button automatically redirects them to a payment page. I'm super new to coding, so I'm not sure if this is possible, but any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please may you edit the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: It's possible. `location.href = URL`.

Comment: Please consider using an `a` element instead of a `button`

Comment: @guest271314 Thanks! Where would I include the location.href?

Comment: @evolutionxbox just edited, does that help?

Comment: @James I wasn't trying to edit it in the browser, the site is through squarespace which allows you to insert javascript

Comment: Currently the button submits a form and presumably creates an account.  Do you want to keep that functionality or just have the button instead redirect to a different page.

Comment: You probably want to prevent default form submission in an `submit` event listener then redirect the Web page in the same even listener. You can also just use the form itself to direct to the target location https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#action.

Comment: @James Exactly correct! I would like to keep that functionality, and have it redirect

Comment: @guest271314 the form is squarespace's account creation form, so I don't have access to any of the source code

Comment: Jake that is a vital piece of info, consider editing that into your question.

Comment: @James Apologies, just included it in there.

Comment: Added tag [tag:squarespace]

Comment: Looks to be the same question: [redirect after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60424825/redirect-to-page-after-successfully-entering-in-information-in-squarespace).  Conclusion appears to be you have to handle it client side - eg store a cookie then on the logged-in page, if the cookie is there redirect.   The "normal" solution would be to send a 302 back from the login post.

Answer (score 0):

`click` and `keydown` event listeners to your rescue.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.yWSHVqDY3QXtLSenwRoA')
btn.addEventListener('click', () => location.href = 'https://google.com')
btn.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.key == 'Enter') {
    location.href = 'https://google.com'
  }
})
```

```html
<button class="yWSHVqDY3QXtLSenwRoA" data-test="create-account-create-button" type="submit"><span>Create account</span></button>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to run this on a squarespace site, and the code didn't run. I tried adding <script> tags before and after, but that still didn't work. Any idea on how to make this work?

Comment: @JakeGlidden I'm not familiar with squarespace unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In a form you would use the action attribute to specify where the form submit to.

```html
<form action="/create_account" method="get">
  <button class="yWSHVqDY3QXtLSenwRoA"
    data-test="create-account-create-button" type="submit">
    <span>Create account</span>
  </button>
</form>
```

If you have more buttons in the same form you can use the formaction attribute on the button to override the default:

```html
<form action="/login" method="get">
  <button class="yWSHVqDY3QXtLSenwRoA" formaction="/create_account"
  data-test="create-account-create-button" type="submit">
    <span>Create account</span>
  </button>
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```